# How should I troubleshoot a "round error" in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

I have set up a CommCare form in the form builder, when I try to deploy I receive the following message at the top of the screen: "Validation Error: The round function was provided the incorrect number of arguments:2. It expected 1 arguments."

The error also points to which form the error is stemming from, but not where in the form it is being triggered. What should I look for in the form to debug this error?

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that your form uses the `round()` function with two arguments instead of one. You could approach this by viewing the Source XML of your application and then searching for the text `round`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to quickly find a calculation in your form is to open up the App Summary page, click on "Calculations" and "Display Conditions", then search for the word `round`.